# Import calendar library in my android app

Tags: java, android, import

I am new to android and i want to use week calendar in my app i.e from link

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Can i include this in my app. so that i can use  in layout .Will just adding the library in gradle dependencies solve the purpose 
like including external jar in java, do we have something of that sort here as well or  i need to copy paste the source in my app

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you read the "Usage" paragraph in the URL you provided?

Comment: the link you provided itself has all the explanation you need to implement it...

Comment: @Selvin See my answer

Comment: @Selvin There's no point in being ironic here

Comment: I know i sounded a bit silly but i already mentioned i am new to programming so thought of asking it over here now i understood thanks fiddler for being generous and clearifying my doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the project's page, if you use Gradle for your project (which should be the case if your created it in Android Studio), then you need to add the following line in the `dependencies` section of your `app/build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
```

That's it.